# Problem with headers generation in image upload Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I´m trying to upload an image with Python 3, this is my upload method:

```
def load():
    headers = {'X-API-Key' : adminTokenSession}
    image= {'image': open ('C:/Users/Cesar/Desktop/A-FT-DIVT.jpg', 'rb')}
    res = requests.post(activityInfoURL, files= image, headers = headers)
    print (res.text)
```

In the server I check if format is `jpg` or `png` like this:

```
if (files.image[0].headers['content-type'] != 'image/jpeg' && files.image[0].headers['content-type'] != 'image/png') {
    logger.warn("Trying to upload a different format file")
    res.json({ error: "The file must be an image" })
```

I´m always getting ***"The file must be an image"*** error and I think it´s because headers are not created.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to post an image, instead of an open file descriptor:

```
headers = {'X-API-Key' : adminTokenSession}

# Note here
with open('C:/Users/Cesar/Desktop/A-FT-DIVT.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    image = {'image': f.read()}
# Note:               ^^^^^^^^

res = requests.post(activityInfoURL, files= image, headers = headers)
```